# Kivy window set_title changes back to main file name

Tags: kivy

When I set the window title, the title is set back to it's corresponding file name.

```
class myniceApp(App):
    global Window
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (.95,.95,.95,1)
        Window.size = (1024, 768)
        Window.set_title('mykivyapp')
        Builder.load_string(style)
        homewin = MyniceappHome()
        homewin.initapp()
        return homewin
myniceApp().run()
```

In the above example, the title 'mykivyapp' is shown initially but set back to the filename after homewin.initapp()

How should set_title() be used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Window title is set with [`App.title`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.title), not with Window directly:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello world'
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use it like below.. this one worked for me.. i tried the first solution explained above, but it did not work.. so i change a bit and put the title outside the build function, its working successfully..

```
class controllerApp(App):
    title = 'Vehicle Detection System'

    def build(self, video_source=VIDEO_SOURCE):
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to explain your answer a little bit.